# Pandas if condition is True perform function to next n rows

Tags: pandas, array-broadcasting

I have a column of indicator functions(a), which when true I want to perform an action on the next n(3 in this example) rows of another column(b). The following achieves what I am looking for but will get very inefficient as n gets large :
[image]

Are there other ways to do this? I am trying to avoid loops.

Comment: I don't think there is any way around loops . May I know why you want to avoid them ?

Comment: @SHIVANSHNARAYAN performance and I tend to find looping through dataframes very unintuitive - much prefer setting up a single object similar to the example shown.

Comment: Instead of pasting a screenshot, please include code along with sample data.  See this [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky but possible using an apply:

```
testing = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    'b': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})

def func(value, n):
    if value.a == 0 and value.b != -1:
        value.b = 0
    elif value.a == 1 and value.b == 0:
        value.b = 0
        testing.loc[value.name + 1:value.name + n, 'b'] = -1
    elif value.a == 1 and value.b == -1 and testing.loc[value.name, 'a'] == 1:
        testing.loc[value.name - 1, 'b'] = -1
        testing.loc[value.name + 1:value.name + n, 'b'] = -1

    return value

testing.apply(func, axis = 1, args = (3,))
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  0 -1
3  0 -1
4  0 -1
```

Comment: thanks chico, had something like this in mind. Although, looks like a for loop might just be best way to go about this.